# Informix SQL to get date range that changes automatically

Tags: sql, informix

Please help me with an Informx SQL query to be run every Friday.
Period: 1st of the Month to the Thursday before the Friday that it is being run on. I can't just choose date ranges as it will be an auto report so the dates needs to update automatically.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Apologies, this is my query but I still struggle with the date range as this works for now but wont auto change next week? I am still relatively new.

**select tpdat,tacno,tecod,topno,tcloc,tegrp,tegzc,tedes,
tunit,ttotv,ffval, admpat.pmeda, admpat.padmd, todat
from trnteq, admpat
where trnteq.tacno = admpat.patno
and tpdat between "01-09-2016" and "15-09-2016"
order by tcloc**

Comment: I figured out to get the day before the report is run by doing the following;
**tpdat between "01-09-2016" and today -1**
I now just need to get the first of the month then I am sorted?

Comment: THis is what I have now, but I get syntax error when I run it?

**_select tpdat,tacno,tecod,topno,tcloc,tegrp,tegzc,tedes,
tunit,ttotv,ffval, admpat.pmeda, admpat.padmd, todat
from trnteq, admpat
where trnteq.tacno = admpat.patno
and tpdat between (month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @mydate), 0) AS StartOfMonth
and today -1
order by tcloc_**

Comment: I thought I would just put it out there. I got it working see below.

**_select today start from csthead
where d9 = "$"
into temp daterange;
update daterange set start = (lastmonth(today +1 units month,"S"))
where 1 = 1;
unload to /u/BrowDir/City_THT_EquipSept2016.xls
select tpdat,tacno,tecod,topno,tcloc,tegrp,tegzc,tedes,
tunit,ttotv,ffval, admpat.pmeda, admpat.padmd, todat
from trnteq, admpat, daterange
where trnteq.tacno = admpat.patno
and tpdat between start and today -1
order by tcloc_**

Answer (score 1):

You've got two issues: the start of the month and the date of last Thursday. The simplest expression to identify the 1st day of the current month is:

```
MDY(MONTH(TODAY), 1, YEAR(TODAY))
```

The way to identify the most recent Thursday is via a `CASE` statement on `WEEKDAY(TODAY)`. Something like:

```
CASE 
     WHEN WEEKDAY(TODAY) < 5 -- (Sunday (0) - Thursday (4))
     THEN TODAY - WEEKDAY(TODAY) - 3 -- Calc last Sunday, back 3 days
     ELSE TODAY - WEEKDAY(TODAY) + 4 -- Calc last Sunday, forward 4 days
END
```

Note, you will still run into issues where the 1st of current month is later than the most recent Thursday. But hopefully the examples above will point you in the right direction.

Of course, if you know this report is only ever going to be run on Fridays, then calculating the most recent Thursday is just `TODAY -1`.